# Comparing two POJOs in Java

Tags: java, equals, comparator, comparable

I have two objects which has multiple properties. Please note one of these objects is given to me via Db->JAXB route (from some XML schema) and hence I can't  implement Comparator and Comparable on this. Reason I say this is I have used Comparable and Comparator in past for comparing two objects equality on multiple properties but unfortunately can't do it.

So imagine like this

```
Class A {
    String value1;
    String value2,
    ...
    String valueN;
}

Class B {
    String bVal1;
    String bVal2;
    String bVal3,
    String bValN;
}
```

Class B has extra properties which A does not. These objects are not identical.

I have been comparing like:

```
getBVal1().equals(getValue1()) (Have omitted getters from classes)
getBVal2.equals(getVlue2())
....
```

What is the most efficient way in terms of performance.
Both objects can have max of 20 String/int kind of attributes.

Comment: you can java reflection

Comment: is the value count always the same? if so: why do oyu have 2 classes that are not related?

Comment: One is from a XML schema->POJO and another one is POJO which is retrieved from database (and ofcourse converted in the process via some other API)... So basically I get ObjectB from some API call which goes to DB, creates the POJO using some generated mechanism. I need Object A for something since I filter attributes out of B and can't send A back in my API.

Comment: You need one location to maintain the mapping of properties between two different class. The approach you are following is efficient and type safe. You can keep this code inside a separate utility class.

Comment: Thanks Amit. So it seems the approach I am following to compare two objects should be good from performance perspective since it seems there is no other better way to compare two object's properties where implementing comparator/comparable is not a viable option.